# PDF printing from Selenium with chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to implement printing html/css contents as PDF with Selenium, chromedriver and python.

I could printing with a below code, but I cannot change printing setting. I would like to print in Letter size and no header/footer. Official information [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-chromeOptions-object) or [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) doesn't tell me a lot, so I'm in trouble. Does anyone know that how printing setting can be changed or it can never be done.

```
import json
import os
from selenium import webdriver

# setting html path
htmlPath = os.getcwd() + "\\sample.html"
addr = "file:///" + htmlPath

# setting Chrome Driver
chromeOpt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
appState = {
   "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}
prefs = {
    'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(appState)}
chromeOpt.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chromeOpt.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('.\\bin\\chromedriver', options=chromeOpt)

# HTML open and print
driver.get(addr)
driver.execute_script('return window.print()')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add --headless and try it like this:

```
pdf = driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.printToPDF", {
  "printBackground": True
})

import base64

with open("file.pdf", "wb") as f:
  f.write(base64.b64decode(pdf['data']))
```

Here are some options you can [fiddle with](https://vanilla.aslushnikov.com/?Page.printToPDF)

Comment: Chromedriver 2.39 doesn't work, but after I update to a latest version (79.0.3945.36 for my environment), it does work.  Thank you so much.

Comment: any idea, if we can add preference with headless browser?

Comment: Not working for me with error `Printing not available` > selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Printing is not available"}