# How do i disable headers and footers Selenium Printing

Tags: python, selenium

Does anyone know how to disable the "headers and footers" option while printing in selenium? It's by default set to true, Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!!!

````
import json
import os
from selenium import webdriver

# setting html path
htmlPath = os.getcwd() + "\\sample.html"
addr = "file:///" + htmlPath

# setting Chrome Driver
chromeOpt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
appState = {
   "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}
prefs = {
    'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(appState)}
chromeOpt.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chromeOpt.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('.\\bin\\chromedriver', options=chromeOpt)

# HTML open and print
driver.get(addr)
driver.execute_script('return window.print()')```
````

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893671/pdf-printing-from-selenium-with-chromedriver

Comment: That doesnt work for me

Comment: Why are you using --kiosk-printing?

Comment: @DMart when you have the `--kiosk-printing` option, chrome does not prompt the print dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `"isHeaderFooterEnabled": False` to your `appstate` this below change.

```
appState = {
   "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2,
    "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False
}
```

**Screenshot :** commented `chromeOpt.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')` line just to show the de-selected option in screenshot.
[image]

You can find the details about the chromium options on the below page

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/eadef3f685cd9e96e94fcb9645b6838b6d0907a8/chrome/browser/resources/print_preview/data/model.js

[image]

Comment: asking out of curiosity, where do you get these options from? I looked in chromium website, searched for command line options of chrome, but found nothing.

Comment: @naveennamani Updated the answer with the link and screenshot where you can find different options of the print-preview. FYI, the source is from the Chromium repo.

Comment: this gonna help me always, I'll dig more into the chromium source code now, and thank a lot for the answer

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `Selenium` by following `pyppeteer` examples.

You will need to be able to send commands to chromium and call [Page.printToPDF](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF) Devtools API as shown in the following snip:

```py
    result = send_cmd(driver, "Page.printToPDF", params={
             'landscape': False
            ,'margin':{'top':'1cm', 'right':'1cm', 'bottom':'1cm', 'left':'1cm'}
            ,'format': 'A4'
            ,'displayHeaderFooter': False
            ,'scale': 1
    })

    with open(out_path_full, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(base64.b64decode(result['data']))
```

I've included a full example in my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/Selenium2Pdf) with more settings that are available.