# python selenium chrome print without borders

Tags: python, selenium, printing

I'm trying to use selenium python binding to print from Chrome.

Thanks to [How do i disable headers and footers Selenium Printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609330/how-do-i-disable-headers-and-footers-selenium-printing) I found out that setting "isHeaderFooterEnabled" to False disables headers/footers.

But how can I disable margins for printing in selenium? Default is with margins on.

Thanks!

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609330/how-do-i-disable-headers-and-footers-selenium-printing

Comment: @Mr. Brad - That is the very same link OP added. The question is how to disable margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'marginsType': 1`. I found this in `~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`.