# Headless Chrome Webdriver Issue after printing the web page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a program that goes to Google, and saves the page as a PDF (saves in the directory as the Python file). That's great, but I don't want the Chrome window to open. With a Google search, I found that I can use `options.headless = True`. But after I put that in my code, it doesn't print the page. How can I fix this issue? The code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json
import os

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False  # Setting this to True won't make the page printing work

options.add_argument("--kiosk-printing")

settings = {
    "recentDestinations": [{
        "id": "Save as PDF",
        "origin": "local",
        "account": ""
    }],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2,

}

prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings),
         "savefile.default_directory": str(os.path.realpath('.')),
         }

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.execute_script("window.print();")
```

Thank you for your help!

~helloworld

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893671/pdf-printing-from-selenium-with-chromedriver Does this answer your question?

Comment: hmmm I don't know. How should I put that in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: preference is not supported for headless browser

As of march , 2021

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925

Headless chrome doesn't support preferences setting .

### The thing you could do is :

```
import subprocess

mycmd = r'"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless "https://www.google.com" --print-to-pdf="C:\Users\prave\Downloads\travelBA\test\delete\a.pdf"'
subprocess.run(mycmd)
```

This will save the pdf of google as a.pdf in the path specified. But this is one time operation.

**Recommended Approach:**

**use chrome dev tool protocol (PDF creation only works in headless mode):**

```
import json
from base64 import b64decode
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from datetime import datetime

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://emicalculator.net/")

a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#loanamountslider")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(
    a).click_and_hold().move_by_offset(0, 0).perform()

a = driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
    "Page.printToPDF", {"path": 'html-page.pdf', "format": 'A4'})
print(a)
# Import only b64decode function from the base64 module

# Define the Base64 string of the PDF file
b64 = a['data']

# Decode the Base64 string, making sure that it contains only valid characters
bytes = b64decode(b64, validate=True)

# Perform a basic validation to make sure that the result is a valid PDF file
# Be aware! The magic number (file signature) is not 100% reliable solution to validate PDF files
# Moreover, if you get Base64 from an untrusted source, you must sanitize the PDF contents
if bytes[0:4] != b'%PDF':
    raise ValueError('Missing the PDF file signature')

# Write the PDF contents to a local file
f = open('file.pdf', 'wb')
f.write(bytes)
f.close()
```

Comment: Wait for the first option, how do I do it?

Comment: If you pass that argument to chrome then the pdf will be created at that location during chrome driver object creation

Comment: Be aware that `Print.printToPDF` currently *only* works in headless mode! https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/939ac7f/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions

Comment: Great...works seamlessly